# ¿Por qué cuando se hay errores de mysql (ejem clave duplicada) desde php 8, se rompen las páginas?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Desde que actualicé el servidor a ubuntu 22.04 con php 8 me sucede lo siguiente... Cuando alguna sentencia SQL debe generar un error, en lugar de devolver error y poder capturarlo el servidor rompe la página por ese punto y no interpreta nada más, ni php y el html literal de la página. He intentado hacerlo con transacciones y me pasa lo mismo. A partir de la línea donde se ejecuta la sentencia SQL el navegador no muestra nada más.

```
$sSQL="insert into ... ";
$result=mysqli_query( $conexion, $sSQL);    <-- (cuando los datos a insertar tienen la clave 
                                                duplicada, no pasa de aquí.)
if ($result==1){
    echo "Falta guardada correctamente.<Br>";
}else{
    echo "Parece que ha sucedido algún error al guardar las faltas.";
}
```

Esto no pasaba en las versiones anteriores ni tampoco pasa en el servidor de prueba del XAMPP, por lo que supongo que será algún tema de configuración

Comment: Supongo que ha de ser la validación sobre la sentencia de MySQL, ya que no se cumple dicha condición y por ello no hay respuesta que dar, intenta validar **$result === true**

Comment: Prueba con `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL ^ MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` después de crear la conexión.

Comment: Seguramente esta lanzando una excepción, como no las estas capturando la ejecución termina de inmediato. Si no ves el motivo del error es porque no tienes configurado en PHP el [`error_reporting`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting)

Comment: ¿Qué dice el log de errores? Muchas cosas han cambiado en PHP 8, por lo que el código puede fallar también por otros motivos.

Answer (score 2):

¡Perfecto! Muchas gracias a todos por vuestras rápidas respuestas. Finalmente lo he podido resolver como dice Marcos, capturando las excepciones. Este es el código tal y como ha quedado. Se puede simplificar más, pero así se entiende mejor.

```
$sSQL="insert into....";
try {
    $result=mysqli_query( $conexion, $sSQL);    
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $result=0;
}
if ($result==1){
    echo "Falta guardada correctamente.";
}else{
    echo "Parece que ha sucedido algún error al guardar las faltas";
}
```